# How do I load a 24 bit tiff image in C++

Tags: image, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

How do I load a 24 bit tiff image in C++. I tried using cvLoadImage from openCV to load the image, but it failed. The compilation occurs but the image doesn't load. Plz help. Is there any standard library I can use for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably read it using Qt, try this:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html

The documentation states it can read tiff, and that it has support for QImage::Format_RGB666.